# How to restore/revert back to original Mac address of my network adapter on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, mac-address

For any reason, I changed my MAC address from network adapter properties>config>Advanced>Network Address. and set a value. It changed immediately after auto disconnecting and reconnecting.

After solving my problem, I've changed it back to 'Not Present' radio button selected. But the MAC address hasn't been reverted.

I,

- Restarted my PC. Nothing.
- Unplugged the network cable, restarted the PC. Replugged. Nothing
- Unplugged the network cable, changed my MAC again, then selected 'Not present' again, disabled-enabled network adapter, plugged the cable. No hope.

Now I'm not seeing any way to change it back except entering original MAC address manually. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: I cannot speak for its effectiveness, but this article suggests a third-party tool which you might wish to try (scroll towards the bottom, past the steps you've already taken) - - http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-restore-your-network-cards-original-mac-address

Comment: Thanks for reply. The third party app shows 'failed to restore' even though it was showing the original MAC. But I have solved it at last. The same way how it locked me. I set the network Address value to original one, then restarted my PC, so this original one is fixed now (don't know why), then selected it back to "Not Present". The MAC did not change but the "Not Present" option also selected. It is working now. I think it is a bug. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Could definitely be a bug. I am glad it seems you have worked it out, though. =)